Boundary of sublevel of function
Suppose we are given a function
$$ h \colon \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}. $$
I am trying to find minimal hypotheses on the regularity of $h$ under which the boundary of
$$ C = \{h(x) \leq 0 \} $$
is
$$ D = \{h(x) = 0 \}. $$
Clearly, this is the case when $h$ is countinuously differentiable and $0$ is a regular value for $h$. Can we say something more? For example, what if $h$ is analytic? Any reference is appreciated.
Thank you in advance.

I am guessing by "analytic" you are assuming that something like the maximum principles for complex analytic functions must hold. But since the codomain is $\Bbb R$, complex analytic does not apply, and the maximum principle does not hold for real analytic functions. For example $f(x) = -x^2$ is real analytic. Besides which, if it did hold, "analytic" would be a stronger hypothesis, not weaker.
